# MS Chart Parsing ChartType from a string

Tags: c#, charts

I want to parse the ChartType from a dropdown list but I couldnt parse the value,
Is there anyway to parse it ?

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
...
...
Chart2.Series[0].ChartType = Enum.Parse(typeof(SeriesChartType.Area), DropDownList1.Text);
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: typeof(SeriesChartType) doesn't work either !

Comment: nope it doesnt work with the ignore case either

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could populate the `DropDownList1` with the enumeration.

The string representation of the enumeration name would be displayed as the text in `DropDownList1`.

`DropDownList1.Items.AddRange = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SeriesChartType));`

Then you can access the items of the list.

`Chart2.Series[0].ChartType = (SeriesChartType)DropDownList1.SelectedItem;`

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to specify .Area:

```
Chart2.Series[0].ChartType = Enum.Parse(typeof(SeriesChartType), DropDownList1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

your MS control has a Type

i.e  Chart.Series[0].TypeName = DropDownList.Selectvalue.text

only work on the Control its self if you refrence the using

System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting and create an object from that it wont work